# wget creates many additional files

Tags: bash, shell, wget

I have a server with set htaccess. When I want to download files from it I simply execute:

`wget -r --user="user" --password="password" -q 'http://server'`

All files are downloaded but `wget` creates also many additional files `index.html?something` in each directory and I have to manualy remove them. Is to possible to not create that files?

Comment: What does the "something" correlate to? Is it a post variable being triggered by the crawl, is it the username?

Comment: It creates files like: `index.html?A=B&C=D` what is in my opinion strange because `index.html` is a static page without anything like php or javascript.

Comment: It's difficult to advise further without seeing the content you are attempting to crawl.

Answer (score 1):

See the `--accept` and `--reject` options, if your version of `wget` suppors them:

> > ```
> > -A acclist --accept acclist
> > -R rejlist --reject rejlist
> > ```
> >
> > Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to accept or reject. Note that
> >     if any of the wildcard characters, *, ?, [ or ], appear in an element of acclist or rejlist,
> >     it will be treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix.